# Turing machines: can a machine write to a finite number of memory cells, but not halt?

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, halting-problem

I am trying to reduce the Halting problem to show another problem is undecidable. The problem involves a program that is true if a machine $M$ writes to an arbitrary amount of memory, and false if it writes to a finite amount of memory cells. I am now thinking, is writing to a finite amount of memory cells equivalent to halting, or can there be cases where a machine writes to a finite amount of memory cells without halting?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a Turing machine that repeatedly moves its head right, then left, then right, then left, and so on.

Comment: I didn't think of that! Good example. I'm thinking, could we somehow deduce if a machine halts by knowing it writes to finite memory?

Comment: This sounds like a completely different question.